# Javaws unable to locate JRE on 10.9 Mavericks

Tags: macos, command-line, java

From the command line, running javaws results in the message:

```
$ javaws
No Java runtime present, requesting install.
Unable to locate a Java Runtime to invoke.

$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_40-b43)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.0-b56, mixed mode)

$ /usr/libexec/java_home -V
Matching Java Virtual Machines (3):
    1.7.0_40, x86_64:   "Java SE 7" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.6.0_51-b11-457, x86_64:   "Java SE 6" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_51-b11-457.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.6.0_51-b11-457, i386: "Java SE 6" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_51-b11-457.jdk/Contents/Home
```

I'm running OSX 10.9.

What's the matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. Updating my java version from [java.com](https://www.java.com/en/download/mac_download.jsp)  did it for me.

Comment: You're right -- upgrading to java build 1.7.0_45 worked for me!